# Redirect subdomain to domain with change in path

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress multisite installation with subdomains. I want to redirect one of my subdomain to domain in the following manner:

- subdomain.domain.com => domain.com
- subdomain.domain.com/pages => domain.com/pages
- subdomain.domain.com/category-X/posts => domain.com/category-X/posts
- subdomain.domain.com/category-Y/one-old-subcategory/posts => domain.com/one-new-subcategory/posts
- subdomain.domain.com/categories/subcategories/posts => domain.com/subcategories/posts

I couldn't find correct order and rewrite rules to achieve that.
Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First redirect everything that's specific:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^categories/subcategories/(.*)$ http://domain.com/subcategories/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^category-Y/one-old-subcategory/(.*)$ http://domain.com/one-new-subcategory/$1 [L,R]
```

Then everything else:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon for reply. I have 4 categories and 15 subcategories so will you please generalize the first RewriteRule. Also Rewrite rule  for one-old-subcategory matches with first RewriteRule too. Willn't it be affected?

Comment: So if I have 20 pages,  sub.main.org/page1 > main.org/newpage1 . I will need to add 20 rules? One for each page and one for the homepage and 404's?